# Creating a "feed" out of

Tags: java, arraylist, feed

**Here's the larger problem statement:**

There is a source of data that gives me a bunch of records(~30,000) every hour in the form of a CSV. I need to convert this to a "feed" of sorts, basically returning 'n'(0-50) records(after some computation over them) at every HTTP GET call.

Every person logging in at a time will see the same set of 'n' records.

Expected QPS = 5,000

**My approach:**

Since the total number of records per hour are not huge and since the reads have to be faster, I thought I could process each incoming record and put 'n' records into a list. 
At a delta time, I will replace the elements in the list with new 'n' elements.

**My problem**

1. How do I replace this list which is being read at every HTTP call without affecting the on-going reads?
2. Is this even the right approach (completely in memory)? I did not want to use any larger softwares such as DBs or message queues if a simple Java approach can do the QPS I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If the size is fixed then use an Array instead of a List.
And maintain 2 arrays having a flag canServe set this to true  if it is valid  and keep the other array ready to serve when the first one is notValid anymore.
And switch between this arrays.